# Injective functions of matrices?

Tags: matrices, functions

**How do I know wether a function that is clearly injective when acting on $\mathbb{R}$ is also injective on matrices?**

To give a specific example how can I conclude $A=B$ from $e^A = e^B$ if $A$ and $B$ are matrices of the same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a generic matrix and $B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then $e^A=e^B$ implies that there is a polynomial $P\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ s.t. $B=P(A)$; moreover, the matrix $P(A)-A$ is similar to a matrix in the form $2i\pi .diag((k_j)_j)$ where the $k_j$ are integers.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually not true for the exponential : for
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$you can compute and find that
$$e^{tA}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t & -\sin t\\ \sin t & \cos t \end{pmatrix},$$
which is periodic with respect to $t$. In particular $e^{2\pi A}=e^0$.

The problem is that even a real matrix can have complex eigenvalues, so if your function is not injective once you extend it to the complex plane, then you can lose injectivity with real matrices as well. As another (related) example, the function $x\mapsto x^3+x$ is increasing, thus injective on $\mathbb{R}$; but the matrix $A$ defined above is such that $A^2=-I$, so you get $A^3+A=0=0^3+0$ even though $A\neq 0$.

Comment: for the exponential in particular can one write down in general for which cases it is true?

Comment: I think that as long as your matrices $A$ and $B$ only have real eigenvalues, it should work. It is at least true if they are diagonalizable, but I am less sure about the case where they have a non-diagonal Jordan form.